# Как продолжить запись в файл, если его необходимо открывать несколько раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пишу Телеграм бота на Python и у меня есть необходимость записывать некоторые значения в текстовый файл. Я пишу

```
def writeInLog(string):
    logs = open('Logs.txt', 'w')
    logs.write(str(time.ctime(time.time())) + ": " + string + '\n')
    logs.close()
```

Но в таком случае он каждый раз перезаписывает строку, удаляя то, что было раньше. Если я выношу `logs = open('Logs.txt', 'w')` за функцию, и удаляю `logs.close()` то он вовсе ничего не пишет. Если оставить `logs.close()`, то он выдаёт ошибку при второй записи. В интернете не нашёл подходящего решения. Заранее спасибо за разъяснение моей проблемы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Судя по названию файла, вы записываете логи. Это можно реализовать намного проще с помощью встроенной библиотеки logging. С помощью настройки логера можно записывать в файл или же использовать иные Handler для оброботки логов. Так же возможно настроить вид логов для вашей задачи!

Answer (score 1):

Режим доступа к открываемому файлу у вас **'w'**, а это значит файл открывается для записи и указатель стоит в начале файла. Соответственно при следующем открытии данные перезаписываются. Используйте режим **'a'** - открытие с добавлением данных в конец файла.

Так же лучше использовать следующую конструкцию, она исполнит нужные инструкции и автоматически закроет файл, после выполнения

```
def function(string):
    with open('file.txt', 'a') as logs:
       logs.write(string) // ваши действия со строкой
```